# Некорректно отображаются данные выгруженные из API

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

В рамках одного тестового задания делал небольшой сайт, куда из https://swapi.dev выгружаются планеты, а при нажатии на планету отображаются данные по планетам.

С отображением планет вопросов нет, все выгружается. Но вот в отображении данных по планетам есть вопрос. Все данные внутри api планеты - имеют конкретные значения, кроме резидентов, там ссылка.

Поэтому было принято решение делать запрос внутри запроса, реализовано это примерно так:

```
function fetchPlanet(id){
    'use strict';
    fetch(`http://swapi.dev/api/planets/${id}`)
      .then( function(response){
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(function(json){
        console.log("data", json)
  
        if (!json.name){
          return;
        }
            
        const name = json.name;
        const population = json.population;
        const rotation_period = json.rotation_period;
        const orbital_period = json.orbital_period;
        const terrain = json.terrain;
        const residents = json.residents;

        for (var key in residents) {
            fetch (residents[key])
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.json()
                })
                .then(function(json){
                    console.log("data", json)

                    if (!json.name){
                        return;
                    }

                const resName = json.name;
                const resGender = json.gender;

                    const html = `
                            
                    <div class="person flex">
                        <div class="person_name">Name: ${resName}</div>
                        <div class="person_gender">Gender: ${resGender}</div>
                    </div>
                            
                    `
                    document.querySelector("#residents").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
                })
            //alert("Ключ: " + key + " значение: " + residents[key] );
        }
        
        const html = `
        <div class="character flex">
            <a class="planet_card flex" href="#${name}">
                <h2 class="planet_title title-reset">${name}</h2>
            </a>
            
            <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="${name}"></a>
            <div class="popup">
                <div class="globe-container ${terrain}_small">
                </div>
                <ul class="planet_list list-reset flex">
                    <li class="planet_list_item flex">
                        <div class="planet_name flex">${name}</div>
                    </li>    
                    <li class="planet_list_item flex">
                        <h4 class="param_title flex">Rotation Period:</h4>
                        <div class="param_deskr">${rotation_period} hours</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="planet_list_item flex">
                        <h4 class="param_title flex">Orbital Period:</h4>
                        <div class="param_deskr">${orbital_period} days</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="planet_list_item flex">
                        <h4 class="param_title flex">Terrain:</h4>
                        <div class="param_deskr">${terrain}</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="planet_list_item flex">
                        <h4 class="param_title flex">Population:</h4>
                        <div class="param_deskr">${population} inhabitants</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="planet_list_item">
                        <h4 class="param_title resid">Residents:</h4>
                        <div class="param_deskr flex">
                            <div class="residents flex" id="residents"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="close"title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
            </div>
        </div>`
        
        document.querySelector("#characters").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html)

    })

}
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    fetchPlanet(i)
}
```

Проблема заключается, что при запуске алгоритм как-то сам выбирает какие планеты прогонять через повторный запрос, в общем не могу разобраться.

Comment: С чего ты решил, что "прогоняет через повторный запрос"?

Comment: "было принято решение делать запрос внутри запроса" - почему?)) В чём проблема сделать новый запрос при клике, зачем вам 100500 ненужных запросов?) Если беспокоитесь по поводу того что юзеру надо будет подождать после клика, то это нормальная практика, тем более от вас не требуется моментального показа всей доступной информации. Ну а в дальнейшем можете вообще запомнить сделанные запросы и сразу показывать предыдущие результаты при повторных запросах